# How to make table like spreadsheet (include spanning) in iOS

Tags: ios, html-table

Shortly, I want to make table in iOS.

For example, I take table data(like html table tag) from api server, parse it and draw editable table.

But, iOS System library don't offer col, row spanning. So, I want to know about open source, logic etc about table.

Please, Help me.

Comment: show something what you have tried.

Comment: You want to learn `UICollectionView`.

Comment: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMSpreadsheetView take a look at the url